# Cant download images from URL into datalake using copy activity Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure data factory, copy activity to download an image from URL into a Datalake, the copy activity works as expected example :

[image]

so the image is shown as expected from all the URL configured in Service link except this one :
https://www.sephora.com/productimages/product/p400057-av-03-zoom.jpg

here's the result which I'm getting :

[image]

Do you have any explanations why I'm getting Sephra image like this in the datalake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a transient issue. Checkout my below setup

Source dataset:

[image]

Sink Dataset

[image]

[image]

Datalake:

[image]

Comment: it's really wierd, for me it doest not work with this URL, I have the smae conf as you,

Comment: are you using Anonymous as authentification type in your dataset ?

Comment: yes, correct, am using Anonymous

Comment: are still seeing this issue, after retries for only this image ?

Comment: Yes just with Sephora URLs, it works for the others..I dont know why ..it is really wierd

Comment: Do you have  an explanation why it works with the other URLs and not with sephora URL  please?

Comment: am not sure there can be a number of reasons, seems to be a transient issue . Try saving it as jpg instead or "clear cache and cookies" or try a different browser to rule out local issues

Comment: try refresh a couple of times - [snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQpHf.png)

Comment: anyway, I will mark your answer as the right answer, because I have the same conf as you and moreover it works with the OTHER URLs except sephora...it is really wierd

Comment: I agree, will let you know if I find anything. Meanwhile Checkout  https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000813.htm

Comment: I changed the browser I used the congnitive mode..this same issue

Comment: I found something, when I try to save the image from the browser, it suggests only to save as WEBP file, and not png.or jpeg ..like the other images, maybe it related to that ?

Comment: I observed the same yesterday before posting answer, but I am able to get the file in ADLS with same setup! You have to mention in the filename.extention in sink dataset thatsit. [second snip in answer]

Comment: Yes thats what will make me crazy, why you were able to save it in ADLS and I can't.but you know what, I take the same image but another URLs and it works the problem related just to Sephora

Comment: interesting, can you download the image locally from ADLS and see it correctly ? Aren't other images from same site ?  maybe related to CORS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239529/discussion-between-karthikbhyresh-mt-and-java-user).